# does Xlib have any library call for Window associated process ID?

Tags: linux, process, xlib, xorg, xserver

**goal**: is to collect information about user interactive program in Tracking app.

most efficient way is through process `ID`. the only way i can think of is getting `Xlib` `Window` associated process `ID`, **does other ways around?**

going through documentation, and source code, no clue for Window associated process `ID` attribute, maybe `Xlib` doesn't keep `PID`, **or does it?**

non efficient solution is through `Window` name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xlib doesn't keep process ids - it was designed to work on a variety of OS'es with different process abstractions, and across networks, where a pid on one machine isn't very useful on another machine.

But since most X applications today are being run on Unix-like machines and displayed locally, not over the network, many modern toolkits adopted a convention of storing the process id in a property on the window of that application.  See the [_NET_WM_PID section](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472565744) of the [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) specification for details.

Answer (score 1):

The X server doesn't have that information. In fact, there may not even be a PID available -- clients can connect to an X server over the network.

If all you need to do is identify what program is being used, though, you could look at the [WM_CLASS](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.1.2.9) window property. This property contains a pair of strings that are used to identify the window to the window manager, and usually includes the name of the application.